# What is the rule for using ONLY at the beginning of a sentence that turns a prepositional phrase into a subject?

Tags: word-usage, word-order

> Only under this kind of environment can people live safe.

Without only, it should read: Under this kind of environment, people can live safe. People is the subject and in the normal position. But with only, people and can are reversed. Putting the clauses in reverse works fine -- People can live safe only under this kind of environment.  What is going on here?

Comment: See this helpful blog post: [Inversion](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/inversion.html) - I'm not the author.

Answer (score 0):

> [1] *Only under this kind of environment can people live safe.*
>
> [2] *People can live safe only under this kind of environment*.

In [1] the PP "only under this kind of environment" is not subject but a preposed adjunct in which "only" is placed in front position in the sentence where it triggers subject-auxiliary inversion.

In [2] "only" is not fronted, but simply heads the PP in its basic position after the verb, so there is no inversion. Again, the PP is functioning as an adjunct in clause structure.

Comment: BillJ, Appreciate your expertise. You’re a master of English.

Comment: Masterof English @BillJ may be, but any common-or-garden English speaker like me ought to know that adverbially "safe" should be "safely".  *Only...can people live safely.*